# How to add a relref to a txt file from leaf bundle index file using Hugo?

Tags: markdown, hugo

I'm trying to link a txt file in an `index.md` file in a leaf bundle.
Basically, here is the structure of my folders:

```
content
|--- _index.md
|---folder1
|   |--- folderA
|   |    |--- index.md
|   |    |--- file.txt
...
```

In `index.md`, I've made a `relref` as follow:

```
Here is the [file] ({{< relref "file.txt" >}}).
```

But when I try to run the hugo server, I got the following error:

```bash
$ hugo server
Watching for changes in /[...]/mywebsite/{content,themes}
Watching for config changes in /[...]/mywebsite/config.toml
Start building sites … 
hugo v0.119.0+extended linux/amd64 BuildDate=unknown

ERROR [en] REF_NOT_FOUND: Ref "file.txt": "/[...]/mywebsite/content/folder1/folderA/index.md:20:22": page not found
Built in 126 ms
Error: error building site: logged 1 error(s)
```

As you can understand, the goal here is to display the content of `index.md` (it's working), and to allow users to click on the link to `file.txt` to see or to download its content.

It's seems I'm doing it wrong, but I don't know why and how to fix it...

Comment: why not store `file.txt` in `static/` folder of hugo and refer it in markdown like this ```Here is the [file](/somefiles/file.txt)```

Comment: 2 questions:
* What is the goal? Do you want users to be able click on `file.txt` and view or download `file.txt`?
* Does this structure work to display the generated content of `folder1/folderA/index.html`?

Comment: The goal is to allow users to click on the link to `file.txt` to download it. And yes, actually, the structure works to display the content of the `index.md` in `folderA`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I start from contents folder, then it works. If I don't it gives `REF_NOT_FOUND` error.

So for you the path should be: `folder1/folderA/file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

According to the Hugo [Links and cross references documentation](https://gohugo.io/content-management/cross-references/), ref and relref can only find content documents: not page resources like your file.txt.

You can hyperlink to a page resource in the same leaf bundle without needing a shortcode: just name the file, like this: `Here is the [file](file.txt).`

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering is because the `relref` shortcode is trying to resolve the path to `file.txt` from the context of the current page, which is `index.md`. However, `file.txt` is located in a different leaf bundle, so it's not accessible from the current page.

To fix this, you need to use the absolute path to `file.txt`. The absolute path would be something like `/content/folder1/folderA/file.txt`. You can use the `relURL` shortcode to generate the absolute path, like this:

```
Here is the [file] ({{< relURL "file.txt" >}})
```

This will generate the absolute path to `file.txt` and use that as the URL for the link.

Here's an example of how to use the `relURL` shortcode in your `index.md` file:

```
Here is the [file] ({{< relURL "file.txt" >}})
```

This will generate the following HTML:

```html
<a href="/content/folder1/folderA/file.txt">file</a>
```

This will create a link to `file.txt` that will allow users to click on it to see or download its content.